# DerInputStream.getLength() : lengthTag=109, too big java IOException installing ssl

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, keytool

I want to install SSL into my spring boot application, I have got two file ca_bundle.crt and certificate.crt.
I tried creating keystore PKCS format file using certificate.crt only.
Later I found out there was a blank line left in the crt file, so I removed it.. but did not work.

Then I copied both crt file content into one file without leaving any blank line in between but still same error.

I used keytool to create keystore file.

How to make it work?

Pls note - I am trying to put this pkcs file in my spring boot application

Comment: The steps you followed are incorrect. You wouldn't add a certificate to a PKCS12 keystore. A simple google search will give you many resources on how to secure your spring boot application. Also you haven't mentioned anything about your private key. You cannot secure a server without a private key. Is the certificate.crt the signed certificate of your private key? I just googled `spring boot ssl configuration` and the first 2 results are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @always_a_rookie the first 2 google links you are talking about ..says you need to import it into a keystore and use it to enable HTTPS in a Spring Boot application..................keytool -import -alias tomcat -file myCertificate.crt -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass password..............

Comment: Yes I do have the signed certificate..

Comment: The error you have in the title is because the spring isn't able to read the keystore. Possibly it could have been corrupted during the import or it is configured incorrectly in the application.